# Object Store Throwing error in.3.6.2 Runtime

Tags: mule, esb, persistent-object-store

I am migrating my code from 3.5.1 to 3.6.2 and i am also using  object store to store all the failed records  for some other scenario. I have downloaded the new object store from "install new software"(only community version is available  as i have seen, let me know if enterprise version is also released of object store for 3.6.2 runtime) .

When i am running my application my getting below exception

`Error creating bean with name 'ObjectStore': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.mule.api.registry.Registry org.mule.modules.objectstore.ObjectStoreConnector.registry; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.mule.api.registry.Registry] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}`

And when i am trying to make a separate small utility on object store to test , it is working fine but in my existing code when i am adding object store it is showing  above error.

Please Advice,

@TyroneVillaluna

Cheers,
BeSolver

Comment: Do you have any spring component scanning setup? if so it could be an issue with with your component scanning config excluding the Mule packages. See here: https://github.com/mulesoft/objectstore-connector/issues/14

Comment: Hey Ryan,
Can you please tell how can find out scanning part   actually i am new mule

Please provide more hint or better way to find out..the link you have provided didn't helped.

Comment: See if you have `<context:component-scan>` tag on your Mule XML. If you have that, it will limit the packages to scan to what you specified, thus excluding Mule packages.. If you need to add your own packages, there's a way on the provided link of Ryan.

Comment: Thank you so much... issue resolved...

Answer (score 0):

Check your project and ensure you are not using Context-scan/spring component scanning or annotation config....

If you are using this then you can try disabling the scanning without mule package...